# pecl - gearman - Unable to load dynamic library?

Tags: php, pecl, gearman

I'm setting up the default instance for a new Amazon Elastic Beanstalk cluster however I'm having issues installing the gearman php client via pecl.

I ran `pecl install mongo` without any issues, but after I run `pecl install gearman` it gives the following error:

```
[root@ip ~]# php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gearman.so' - libgearman.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I do have gearmand installed, just the php client is giving me trouble. The php module gearman.so is in the "/usr/lib64/php/modules/" folder too.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately gearman is a bit more complicated to install. You will need to download and compile the gearman server even if you don't intend to use your current server for gearman. It provides the library that you are missing.

If you look at the error message its missing `libgearman.so.8` not `gearman.so`

Comment: oh geez, I got it backwards. I'll compile from source, thanks!

Comment: turns out I had gearman installed, after tons more googling I came across a post that said to execute "ldconfig", once I did that the error disappeared.